# Example REST web service client library with API?

Tags: python, ruby, web-services, api, rest

I'm looking for examples of a nice API for a REST client library, preferably in Python or Ruby, but and language accepted. The library I'm working on wraps a REST service (which acts as a model store). It's tied to the specific service rather than being a generic REST wrapper.

My first instinct was to model it after Django ORM or ActiveModel, but that seems way overly complicated. What are some existing libraries that do a nice job of wrapping REST services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one I use the most is [Cistern](https://github.com/lanej/cistern/)

You can see an example of how to setup a client using it here: [Sample Client](https://github.com/ehowe/ruby-imgur/blob/master/lib/imgur/client.rb)

It supports a `mock` mode as well for offline testing.